# Private field in parent class shadowed/hidden by subclass - inspections to catch it

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, private, code-inspection

I just cracked a tough bug which turned out to be a result of the following scenario:

```
class Parent {
    private Object field;

    public Object getField() {
        return field;
    }

    public void setField(Object field) {
        this.field = field;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {

}

class GrandChild extends Child {
    private Object field;

    public Object getField() {
        return field;
    }
}
```

Now I am fully aware that this is a nasty smell. It took me several days to track down. What I am looking for is an inspection that might highlight this or similar scenarios elsewhere in code. Eclipse or IntelliJ or CheckStyle or Findbugs or anything would be fine.

Essentially I would like to find `private` fields that shadow parent `private` fields.

Comment: What you're referring to is called _hiding_, not shadowing, but there's none of that going on. `field` in `GrandChild` would hide `field in `Parent` only if `field` in `Parent` was accessible, which it isn't.

Comment: Not an answer, but if possible mark those `Parent` methods as final to cause a compile error when a subclass tries to override those methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a specific compiler warning within eclipse.oxygen
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by Robert's post I found it in IntelliJ:

[image: IntelliJ equivalent]